# add column, populate entire column with name of file (without the ".csv") -for multiple files in BaSH

Tags: filenames, csv, columns

Caveat: Absolute beginner. I need to add a column to a .csv file where the column header can be "Name", but the entire column should be exactly the same -- the name of the file itself, the `filename`. Each file has only 3 variables now, but 2100 rows.

Example: For file **"bcc1_45Fall_10010002.csv"** this is what I have -

```
   HUC8       YEAR    RO_MM
   10010002   1961    74.7
   10010002   1962    69.1
   10010002   1963    52.0
   10010002   1964   130.7
   10010002   1965    32.2
   10010002   1966    85.4
```

This is what I want -

```
  NAME                   HUC8       YEAR    RO_MM
  bcc1_45Fall_10010002   10010002   1961    74.7
  bcc1_45Fall_10010002   10010002   1962    69.1
  bcc1_45Fall_10010002   10010002   1963    52.0
  bcc1_45Fall_10010002   10010002   1964   130.7
  bcc1_45Fall_10010002   10010002   1965    32.2
  bcc1_45Fall_10010002   10010002   1966    85.4
```

OR this -

```
  HUC8                    YEAR    RO_MM
  bcc1_45Fall_10010002    1961    74.7
  bcc1_45Fall_10010002    1962    69.1
  bcc1_45Fall_10010002    1963    52.0
  bcc1_45Fall_10010002    1964   130.7
  bcc1_45Fall_10010002    1965    32.2
  bcc1_45Fall_10010002    1966    85.4
```

If I could simply replace all the data in the "HUC8" column with the `filename` that would be perfect. It doesn't need to be an extra column.

I need to do this for many thousand files.

If I knew how to do the first part, I could then create a loop. But maybe there's even a better way?

I don't know where to begin.

Comment: Is the file really comma separated - or separated by whitespace as shown in your examples?

Comment: @steeldriver -a comma. I was just trying to make it more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `awk` and `column`:

```
$ awk '
  NR==1{ sub(/\.csv$/, "", FILENAME) } # remove .csv suffix from FILENAME
  NR>1{ $1=FILENAME }                  # replace the first field with filename
  1                                    # print record
' bcc1_45Fall_10010002.csv | column -t
HUC8                  YEAR  RO_MM
bcc1_45Fall_10010002  1961  74.7
bcc1_45Fall_10010002  1962  69.1
bcc1_45Fall_10010002  1963  52.0
bcc1_45Fall_10010002  1964  130.7
bcc1_45Fall_10010002  1965  32.2
bcc1_45Fall_10010002  1966  85.4
```

---

You could run this in a shell loop to save the modified files to directory `modified_files`:

```
mkdir modified_files &&
for i in *.csv; do
  awk 'NR==1{ sub(/\.csv$/, "", FILENAME) } NR>1{ $1=FILENAME }1' "$i" |
    column -t > "./modified_files/$i"
done
```

---

If you need to replace column `HUC8` and this is not the first column, change the code to this:

```
awk -v search='HUC8' '
  NR==1{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
      if ($i==search){ fld=i; sub(/\.csv$/, "", FILENAME); break }
  }
  NR>1{ $fld=FILENAME }
  1
' file.csv | column -t
```

Comment: Wow. This sounds like just what I want. I will perform it on a test folder first, of course, but would you be so kind as to explain it a little more? I tried googling NR and it said it was the number of read-write operations? This doesn't help me understand what I'm doing. You have commented the code well, I just don't know the commands and would like to learn. Thanks!

Comment: Freddy - @Freddy -it worked GREAT for replacing the info in the "HUC8" column. Unfortunately, it deleted all the info in both other columns (but kept the headers). Simple fix?

Comment: `NR` is the input record number that is currently processed in AWK, i.e. the line number, `NF` (used in the second example with the loop) is the number of fields of the current record/line and `FILENAME` is obviously the name of the current input file (see [Built-in Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Auto_002dset.html) in the GNU Awk manual). The `sub(...)` is a [string function](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) for text replacement and fields (columns) are prefixed with a `$`, i.e. `$1` is the first field.

Comment: Since `,` is the field separator in your files, replace `awk` with `awk -F, -v OFS=,` to change the input and output field separator and remove `| column -t` since you don't need to format the output. Please post real data next time :)

Comment: I was trying to find a chat option so as not to have this take up unnecessary space, but... I don't know what you mean by "real data". Believe me, many of us new guys would like to "play by the rules" but we're so new, we have no idea. I kind of hate asking questions because I know I'm doing it wrong. But I need to have answers, so I persevere. If I knew, I would.

Comment: So, is your second comment telling me how to keep the data in the second and third columns?  I don't know what you mean by "don't need to format the output". I looked up `awk -F` and it seems that would be putting `:` between my data. Why would I do that? I'm very confused.

Comment: Yes, the second comment is telling you to use a comma as field separator (if your data is separated by commas and not by spaces or tabs). That should fix the output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124739/discussion-between-david-montana-and-freddy).

Answer (score 2):

Using [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), and assuming your files are "simple" CSV (no commas **within** fields and so on - you can change `--csvlite` to `--csv` if full RFC-4180 support is required)

```
$ cat bcc1_45Fall_10010002.csv
HUC8,YEAR,RO_MM
10010002,1961,74.7
10010002,1962,69.1
10010002,1963,52.0
10010002,1964,130.7
10010002,1965,32.2
10010002,1966,85.4
```

then

1. to replace the current `HUC8` column:

   ```
    $ mlr --csvlite put -S '$HUC8 = substr(FILENAME,0,-5)' bcc1_45Fall_10010002.csv
    HUC8,YEAR,RO_MM
    bcc1_45Fall_10010002,1961,74.7
    bcc1_45Fall_10010002,1962,69.1
    bcc1_45Fall_10010002,1963,52.0
    bcc1_45Fall_10010002,1964,130.7
    bcc1_45Fall_10010002,1965,32.2
    bcc1_45Fall_10010002,1966,85.4
   ```
2. to add a separate `Name` column:

   ```
    $ mlr --csvlite put -S '$Name = substr(FILENAME,0,-5)' bcc1_45Fall_10010002.csv
    HUC8,YEAR,RO_MM,Name
    10010002,1961,74.7,bcc1_45Fall_10010002
    10010002,1962,69.1,bcc1_45Fall_10010002
    10010002,1963,52.0,bcc1_45Fall_10010002
    10010002,1964,130.7,bcc1_45Fall_10010002
    10010002,1965,32.2,bcc1_45Fall_10010002
    10010002,1966,85.4,bcc1_45Fall_10010002
   ```
3. to add a `Name` column as the first column:

   ```
    $ mlr --csvlite put -S '$Name = substr(FILENAME,0,-5)' then reorder -f Name bcc1_45Fall_10010002.csv
    Name,HUC8,YEAR,RO_MM
    bcc1_45Fall_10010002,10010002,1961,74.7
    bcc1_45Fall_10010002,10010002,1962,69.1
    bcc1_45Fall_10010002,10010002,1963,52.0
    bcc1_45Fall_10010002,10010002,1964,130.7
    bcc1_45Fall_10010002,10010002,1965,32.2
    bcc1_45Fall_10010002,10010002,1966,85.4
   ```

All the above write the result to standard output - to modify the file in-place, add the `-I` option. You can pass multiple files at once using shell globs ex. `bcc*.csv` or `*.csv`.

[When testing **without** `-I` the header line won't be repeated unless a new header is required as a result of record heterogeneity; however with `-I` an appropriate header will be added to each file.]

Answer (score 2):

```
$ perl -lne 'BEGIN {$fnr=1};

             if ($fnr == 1) {
               ($fn = $ARGV) =~ s/\.[^.]+$//;
               print "NAME,$_"
             } else {
               print "$fn,$_"
             };

             $fnr++;

             if (eof) {$fnr=1}' *.csv
```

This will add the filename (without the .csv "extension") as the first field, and print the contents of the .csv files to stdout.

Unlike `awk`, `perl` doesn't keep track of the line count for each individual file (it tracks only the total line count, with the `$.` variable).  This script maintains that count manually, first by setting variable `$fnr` in the BEGIN block, then incrementing it for each line read, and finally by resetting it back to 1 every time the end of a file is reached.

This is easily modified to append the filename as the last field instead of the first.  e.g.  change the two `print` statements to:

```
      print "$_,NAME"
and: 
      print "$_,$fn"
```

If you need to insert the filename field somewhere else in the line, rather than as the first field, you could use perl's `splice` function.

For example, the following inserts the filename as the third field (note that perl array indices start from zero, not 1, so the third field is `$F[2]`, not `$F[3]`):

```
$ perl -F, -lne 'BEGIN {$fnr=1; $field_num=2};

             if ($fnr == 1) {
               ($fn = $ARGV) =~ s/\.[^.]+$//;
               splice @F, $field_num, 0, "NAME";
             } else {
               splice @F, $field_num, 0, $fn;
             };

             print join(",", @F);

             $fnr++;

             if (eof) {$fnr=1}' *.csv
```

This uses perl's `-F` option to set a comma as the field delimiter.  This also enables perl's auto-split feature to automatically split the input line into an array called `@F` (this is similar to awk's default behaviour of auto-splitting the input line into $1, $2, $3, etc).   Either the literal string "NAME" or the modified filename is spliced into @F, then the elements of the `@F` array are printed, joined with comma characters.

Finally, if you want to actually change the contents of the files, use perl's `-i` option.  You can optionally keep a backup of the original file by using an "extension" with the `-i` option, e.g. rename `filename.csv` to `filename.csv.orig` with `-iorig`. For example:

```
perl -iorig -lne '......' *.csv
```

or

```
perl -iorig -F, -lne '......' *.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Then loop over filenames and print columns with awk

```
for f in *.csv;
do
    head -1 $f > out/$f
    cat $f | awk -v FIN=${f%.csv} 'NR>1 {print FIN, $2, $3}' >> out/$f
done

HUC8       YEAR    RO_MM
bcc1_45Fall_10010002 1961 74.7 
(...)
```

Comment: Sorry, apparently I wasn't clear. When I said I had many thousands of files, I meant I was hoping not to have to type in their individual names. I'm looking for something like - in words because I don't know the code - "for any file in this folder, use the `filename` minus the .csv, to replace all the data objects in column "HUC8".